# CSS: How to get overflow working with 2 layers of flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

This is what I want to achieve

[image]

Basically, 2 rows, an input box takes the first row.

The second row should take up the rest of the height. I used flex box with grow to do this.

The second row has 2 columns, the one on the left is a scrollable list.

### Problem

I tried to make a similar component with 2 layers of flexbox, one vertital, and one horizontal.

But when I cannot enable the scrollable overflow. The list is always taller than the screen (I want everything to be contained in screen height). It seems like I have to set a specific height for the scrollable list to make it work, but I used **grow** for its parent flex box and don't know the exactly height.

Here is a draft of mine: https://codepen.io/huakunshen/pen/WNYEJwO

The scrollable list is not overflow, not scrollable and too long. I can make it work by setting a hard height like `height: 10em`. But I want its height to take the rest of the height.

BTW, here is another simlified draft: https://codepen.io/huakunshen/pen/gOQxzmM

In this one, I could easily achieve **flex box grow + overflow** when **there is only a single vertical flexbox**. I just can't get it working when there are 2 layers of flex box.

For the demos, I used **tailwind** to make things tidier.

### Note

- I have tried to use `calc` like `h-[calc(100vh-5rem)]` and it works.However, I don't think that's the best way to do it. I don't want to hard code any height.

Answer (score 0):

Updated to work without hard coding height of the first row.

If you make the parent element `100vh`, then your two flexboxes will probably work:

```html
<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
    <!-- Container -->
    <div style="display: flex; height: 100vh; max-height: 100vh; flex-direction: column; overflow: hidden;">

        <!-- Row 1 -->
        <div style="border: solid 1px #000;">
            Row 1
        </div>

        <!-- Row 2 -->
        <div style="flex-grow: 1; display: flex; overflow: auto; border: solid 1px #000;">

            <!-- Column -->
            <div style="width: 50%; border-right: solid 1px #000; overflow: auto;">
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 1 with scrollable content<br />
            </div>

            <!-- Column -->
            <div style="width: 50%; overflow: auto;">
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
                Column 2 with scrollable content<br />
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: "The second row has 2 columns, the one on the left is a scrollable list."-- The OP wants only the first column to be scrollable.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I tried it on his codes: https://jsfiddle.net/3gfc4jro/

Answer (score 0):

Where you said `h-[calc(100vh-5rem)]`

It should be negative "3rem" not "5rem" (I calculated and tested it)

Container padding (1rem) + input (1.5rem) + margin-top (0.5rem) = 3